# Many to Many Database Relationship Design - to enable Word Clouds

Tags: database, many-to-many, relationship

I'm relatively new to database design and struggling to introduce a many-to-many relationship in a SSAS Tabular model.

I have some 'WordGroup' performance data in one table, like so;

```
WordGroup | IndexedVolume
Dining | 1,000
Sports | 2,000
Movies | 1,600
... and so on
```

Then I have 'Words' contained within these 'WordGroups' sitting in another category table, like so;

```
WordGroup | Word
Dining    | Restaurant
Dining    | Food
Dining    | Dinner
Sports    | Football
Sports    | Basketball
... and so on
```

I can't see Performance data (IndexedVolume) by 'Word' detail - only by the 'WordGroup' that it is contained within. For example above, I can't look at 'Football' IndexedVolume on it's own, I can only choose the 'Sports' WordGroup that contains Football.

However, when analysing by 'WordGroup' I would still like users to understand what 'Words' are included (ideally in a Word Cloud Visualisation). Therefore, I wanted to develop a relationship between these two tables, so when someone chooses a Word Group (or multiple) we can return the Words that are contained within the Word Group(s) - i.e. below.

```
User selects Dining WordGroup
<<<Word Cloud or Flat Table would show Words below>>>
Restaurant
Food
Dinner
```

I looked at Concatenate / Strings etc, but was deterred as the detail here is much more complex and each WordGroup may contain 10+ Words, with translations.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If analizing by WordGroup is an obligatory requirement, you sholud use these tables:
[image]

The many-to-many aplies beacuse your words may be conected to one or more groups, e.g. tree is conected to enviroment, forest, etc.
and obviously one word_group is conected to many words.
To see performance data by Word use :

```
select w.idword , w.name, sum(wg.index_volume)
from word w 
left join word_group_has_word wgw
on w.idword=wgw.word_id
left join word_group wg
on wg.idword_group=wgw.word_group_id

group by w.idword
```

So you will see the sum of all the index volume of all the group_words conected to the words. ANd if you wanna see the words conected to the word groups use:

```
  select distinct w.idword , w.name
    from word w 
    left join word_group_has_word wgw
    on w.idword=wgw.word_id
    where wgw.word_group_id in [listWordGroupsId]
```